# Temporal Expression recognition in Python

Tags: python, regex, expression, temporal

Does anybody know a Python module to easily extract temporal expressions such as `12/01/2011` and `Monday, 12/3/1987` or others (in English format)?

Would like to avoid to build a huge set of regex.

Comment: The locale of python should match the *locale* of the day cf. http://mancoosi.org/~abate/parse-french-dates-enus-machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the standard library you won't find something comprehensive, but if you install [dateutils](http://labix.org/python-dateutil), you can do this:

```
>>> from dateutils import parser
>>> parser.parse('January 12, 2012').strftime('%s')
'1326315600'
>>> parser.parse('01/12/2012').strftime('%s')
'1326315600'
>>> parser.parse('Sunday, 16/09/2012').strftime('%s')
'1347742800'
```

Martijn had a point, so here is the normal representation - which is [`datetime` object](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html):

```
>>> parser.parse('Sunday, 16/09/2012')
datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 16, 0, 0)
>>> parser.parse('01/12/2012')
datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 12, 0, 0)
>>> parser.parse('January 12, 2012')
datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 12, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Why use `.strftime('%s')` in your examples at all?

Comment: To demonstrate that it is parsing values correctly. It normally returns datetime objects.

Comment: Exactly, and those don't demonstrate that the parsing succeeded?

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard `datetime.datetime.strptime()`.

Example:

```
In : datetime.datetime.strptime("12/01/2012", "%m/%d/%Y")
Out: datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 1, 0, 0)
```